# Dynamic height based on content in scrollview

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I currently have two views for an app, "about" and "work." Both pages are in a horizontal scroll view that snaps to feel like a page.

The only problem is when there is a lot of content on one page the other page stretches to be as large which causes there to be a lot of blank space at the bottom.

Here is an example of what I'm talking about.
["About" and "Work Pages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Ilhb.jpg)

```html
<scrollview>
<View>
//small content
</View>
<View>
//large content
</View>
</scrollview>
```

Comment: Please add all the relevant code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the content of each page with a div that has the same height.

```css
.horizontal-pages {
  width: 300px;
  max-height: 400px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.page-slider {
  display: flex;
  flex: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.page-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <section class="horizontal-pages">
    <div class="page-header">
      page header
    </div>

    <div class="page-slider">
      <div class="page-wrapper">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam nisi sem, congue eu diam sit amet, malesuada commodo elit. Ut semper ante id lacus faucibus luctus. Mauris vitae turpis et quam blandit eleifend. Nam laoreet lacus vel egestas molestie. Pellentesque vulputate lacus id orci rutrum dapibus. Proin maximus ligula sit amet justo fringilla volutpat. Integer porta posuere tempus. Aliquam semper blandit est in faucibus.</p>

        <p>Morbi vel metus lorem. Aliquam sapien massa, tempus in vehicula eu, sodales vitae magna. Sed vel rhoncus purus, tristique egestas nisi. Sed cursus nulla elit, nec malesuada augue facilisis sit amet. Morbi placerat euismod magna sit amet euismod. Duis quis feugiat massa, quis scelerisque mi. Curabitur eu quam pretium, auctor metus posuere, bibendum libero. Donec eu diam lectus. Sed pellentesque porttitor leo. Curabitur iaculis neque vel dignissim finibus. Vestibulum placerat sollicitudin dictum. Donec dignissim pharetra leo et finibus. Curabitur venenatis ligula a elit laoreet, id facilisis augue ultricies.</p>

        <p>Aliquam volutpat enim quis ante vehicula faucibus. Fusce aliquet laoreet malesuada. Morbi tristique nibh sit amet nunc posuere, non facilisis velit venenatis. Aliquam id finibus elit, vitae auctor metus. Ut mollis ex vitae metus placerat condimentum. Donec consequat dapibus accumsan. Nullam mollis dui odio, et pharetra urna auctor non.</p>

        <p>Sed sed tellus eu nunc scelerisque mattis. Suspendisse leo dui, congue vitae euismod quis, iaculis et enim. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. In ac condimentum ex. Curabitur tristique velit purus, eget tempus tortor posuere sodales. Nullam vestibulum felis id quam ullamcorper pharetra. Nunc at ultricies purus. Maecenas molestie magna id faucibus lacinia. Vivamus consequat gravida eros, nec pharetra turpis interdum iaculis. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nam feugiat mauris arcu, vel auctor eros faucibus at. Aliquam tincidunt est non arcu sodales aliquet.</p>

        <p>Donec tristique tempor sapien vel vestibulum. Nulla eleifend gravida congue. Donec feugiat arcu sit amet odio posuere, eu lacinia ex iaculis. Fusce a mollis ligula. Donec varius, purus in gravida iaculis, est risus posuere ante, quis tincidunt purus velit sodales ante. Ut ut nulla ligula. Cras enim neque, feugiat dignissim urna pretium, cursus condimentum justo. Praesent mauris quam, vehicula at sem id, sodales consectetur tellus. Suspendisse quis magna rhoncus, dapibus ipsum vel, vulputate lacus. Fusce molestie dui neque, eu iaculis augue porta in. In faucibus interdum massa, et tempor lorem imperdiet a. Aenean sed nulla porttitor, maximus massa eget, pulvinar orci. Suspendisse non volutpat leo, in feugiat dui. Vestibulum eu suscipit purus, in suscipit leo. Nam urna mauris, efficitur vitae commodo non, mollis facilisis massa.</p>
      </div>

      <div class="page-wrapper">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam nisi sem, congue eu diam sit amet, malesuada commodo elit. Ut semper ante id lacus faucibus luctus. Mauris vitae turpis et quam blandit eleifend. Nam laoreet lacus vel egestas molestie. Pellentesque vulputate lacus id orci rutrum dapibus. Proin maximus ligula sit amet justo fringilla volutpat. Integer porta posuere tempus. Aliquam semper blandit est in faucibus.</p>

        <p>Morbi vel metus lorem. Aliquam sapien massa, tempus in vehicula eu, sodales vitae magna. Sed vel rhoncus purus, tristique egestas nisi. Sed cursus nulla elit, nec malesuada augue facilisis sit amet. Morbi placerat euismod magna sit amet euismod. Duis quis feugiat massa, quis scelerisque mi. Curabitur eu quam pretium, auctor metus posuere, bibendum libero. Donec eu diam lectus. Sed pellentesque porttitor leo. Curabitur iaculis neque vel dignissim finibus. Vestibulum placerat sollicitudin dictum. Donec dignissim pharetra leo et finibus. Curabitur venenatis ligula a elit laoreet, id facilisis augue ultricies.</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="page-footer">
      page footer
    </div>
  </section>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to more or less get what I was looking for. I set a conditional for the content in the large view to only show when the scroll was > 0. That way the smaller view isn't stretched when the other view isn't visible